# post requests not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a program that can successfully tell you the weather via post requests.

I'm trying to search the weather on a website and pull the information onto a program, after searching the website with a location(written by the user) for the weather however it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure with what's wrong with the code. Comments and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

location = input('Your location you would like  to know for the weather ' )
print(location)

#http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?   query=bolton&MR=1
url=(r'http://www.wunderground.com' )
values = {
   'query':'location', 
     }

print (values) 
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

print(respData)

paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',str(respData))

for eachP in paragraphs:
  print(eachP)
```

Comment: No error? No output?

Comment: Why go through the pain of scraping (and putting unnecessary load on their servers) when they provide an [API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs) that can return easy-to-process JSON?

Comment: The problem that I seem to occur is that the location isn't actually searching the website for the information.

Comment: You probably should **not** be quoting `'location'` in `'query':'location'`.

Comment: Why don't you use their API? It's free for up to 500 calls per day, rate limited to 10 per minute. See http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs

Comment: I've had a look at the API however it requires a website name. I just want to create a simple python program.